# Making legends for each layers and switching between them using Mapbox GL JS?

Tags: layers, mapbox, legend, mapbox-gl

I created a map using [Mapbox GL JS](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/) with several layers using [this example](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/toggle-layers/)

At the same time I don't have any spatial knowledge in Javascript. It's restrict me to create legends for each layers. The particular legend(s) must show when particular layer(s) switched on.

I find function [L.mapbox.legendControl](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v3.1.1/l-mapbox-legendcontrol/) but how can I use it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v3.1.1/l-mapbox-legendcontrol/ is an example for [Mapbox.js](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox.js) which is a different library to [Mapbox GL JS](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js).

I'm afraid building the legend is something you need to build, not provided by Mapbox GL JS.

https://www.mapbox.com/assembly/examples/legends/ might help with some of the layout design.

Comment: Andrew, thank you for URL to page about assembly css, I really didn't know about it. But it can't help me to make changeble legend field for toggled layers.